# Footer was posistioned after following tutorials to the bottom until I added content?

Tags: html, css, footer

Hi there i'm trying to postilion my footer to the bottom of my page I followed a few tutorials online and I thought it had it and it went to the bottom but as soon as I started adding content so it scrolled it's half way up the page.

I do not need it to appear at all times just under all content...please I'm a beginner trying to learn as I go through tutorials so can you bare that in mind...Thanks in advance!

Here is my style.css

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local(OpenSans), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format("woff")
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444
}
a:hover {
  color: blue
}
section {
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #ebebeb
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: url(blackboardbg.jpg) 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px 30px 37px 0
}
nav li:nth-child(3) {
  padding-right: 200px
}
nav li:nth-child(4) {
  padding-left: 220px
}
.logo {
  background: url(images/logo.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px 211px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 211px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 21px
}
#locator {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: show;
  left: 950px;
  top: 165px;
  z-index: 100
}
p {
  margin: 150px auto 0;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px
}
navmain {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px
}
sectionblank {
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px
}
sectionmain {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px
}
#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative
}
#contentmain {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto
}
#content {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 80px
  /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  /* Height of the footer */
  background: url(blackboardbg.jpg) 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%
}
```

And the index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>
    Casper Creations
  </title>
  <meta content="Casper Creations" name="description">
  <meta content="Lucy Smith" name="author">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <section>
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="buttons/home.png">
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="buttons/about.png">
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="buttons/services.png">
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="buttons/gallery.png">
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="buttons/FAQ.png">
            </li>

            <li>
              <img src="buttons/contact.png">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="logo">
        </div>
      </header>
    </section>

    <p>
    </p>

    <div id="contentmain">
      <div id="locator">
        <img src="callnow.png">
        <br>
      </div>
      test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>test
      <br>
      <b>Categories</b>
      <br>
      <br>
      <i>Kids</i>
      <br>&larr; Frozen
      <br>&larr; Peppa Pig
      <br>&larr; My Little Pony
      <br>&larr; Mr Tumble
      <br>

      <h1>
                    Welcome
                </h1>

      <p>
        Welcome to Casper Creations
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
      <tr style="vertical-align: central">
        <td style="text-align: center; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 12px">
          <b>Special Offers | Advanced Search | Reviews | Create
                        an Account | Log In</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added and adjusted your markup in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvk2qr1m/).
The reason why it wasn't working like intended is, that the `#footer` has `position:absolute;` set to `bottom:0;`, but this position is relative to the next parent with a position other than `static`. I've just moved the `#footer` in the div with the `id="container"` which has `position:relative;` so the footer will be displayed at the bottom.

Because the font color of the footer is white, I've just added a different dummy image for illustration.

As maybe useful further reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local(OpenSans), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format("woff")
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444
}
a:hover {
    color: blue
}
section {
    background: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #ebebeb
}
header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background: url(blackboardbg.jpg) 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 40px 30px 37px 0
}
nav li:nth-child(3) {
    padding-right: 200px
}
nav li:nth-child(4) {
    padding-left: 220px
}
.logo {
    background: url(images/logo.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px 211px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 211px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 21px
}
#locator {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: show;
    left: 950px;
    top: 165px;
    z-index: 100
}
p {
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px
}
#navmain {
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px
}
#sectionblank {
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px
}
#sectionmain {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px
}
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative
}
#contentmain {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto
}
#content {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 80px
    /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    /* Height of the footer */
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/500/60) 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <section>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img src="buttons/home.png">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="buttons/about.png">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="buttons/services.png">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="buttons/gallery.png">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="buttons/FAQ.png">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="buttons/contact.png">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </header>
    </section>
    <p></p>
    <div id="contentmain">
        <div id="locator">
            <img src="callnow.png" />
            <br>
        </div>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br>test
        <br> <b>Categories</b>

        <br>
        <br> <i>Kids</i>

        <br>&larr; Frozen
        <br>&larr; Peppa Pig
        <br>&larr; My Little Pony
        <br>&larr; Mr Tumble
        <br>
         <h1>
                    Welcome
                </h1>

        <p>Welcome to Casper Creations</p>
    </div>
            
<div id="footer">
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <tr style="vertical-align: central">
            <td style="text-align: center; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 12px"> <b>Special Offers | Advanced Search | Reviews | Create
                        an Account | Log In</b>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you your a legend! Really freaked me out when I copied in the code refreshed my browser and saw the cat in the footer, my heart skip a beat looked creepy just these black eyes I had to look over my shoulder! Lol...

Comment: @Lucy'Casper'Smith Glad that I was able to help you, and the cat shock was not intended :) Just thought that would be nicer instead of just adding a colored div or something like that. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed/solved. In case you don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235

Comment: Why I can't put my div layers inside the contentmain div with out the footer rising again...here's what i'm trying to add...

  `<div id="navmain">Column 1</div>
  <div id="sectionblank"></div>
  <div id="sectionmain">Column 2</div>`

and the style.css

`#navmain {
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;

}
#sectionblank {
    width: 60px;
    float: left;

}
#sectionmain {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 700px;
    float: left;

}`

Comment: see above sorry it's a mess don't really know how to use this website yet ^

Comment: @Lucy'Casper'Smith Don't mind, takes some time but you'll get used to it (and there's also a useful 'Help' section). For the new issue: could you add what you currently have as update to your question or in a fiddle? It's easier to see the issue having the current code complete.

Comment: Oh it's ok I found another tutorial about adding a cleared div with the style 

#cleared {
  clear: both;
}

which fixed the problem, thanks again